# UI elements in storyboard are not visible?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

This is the weirdest problem I have ever had with Xcode. I have uploaded a picture of my storyboard and how it should look like. Anyone can tell me what is wrong with this? I have removed and installed Xcode again but still doesn't work.

This is how my storyboard looks like
[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEMr8.png)

This is how it should look like [How should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMMV3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode: Editor > canvas > show Bounds rectangles

This should solve your problem :)